# Adobe Flex: Unable to connect to XMPP server using XIFF library

Tags: actionscript, xmpp, xiff

I am trying to connect to my local XMPP server using the [XIFF library](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/xiff/) however I am unable to do so.

I installed [eJabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/) on my localhost and connected to it with an XMPP client ([Pandion](http://pandion.im/download)) and this is working fine... I am able to connect to the local jabber server.

Next, I tried connecting to the XMPP server using the following code:

LoginView.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Login">
    <s:layout>
        <s:FormLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script source="connection/Connection.as"/>
    <s:Spacer/>
    <s:Label text="Username"/>
    <s:TextInput id="txtUsername" width="200"/>
    <s:Spacer/>
    <s:Label text="Password"/>
    <s:TextInput id="txtPassword" width="200" displayAsPassword="true"/>
    <s:Button id="btnLogin" label="Login" click="login(txtUsername.text, txtPassword.text)" mouseUp="navigator.pushView(HomeView)"/>
</s:View>
```

Connection.as:

```
import org.igniterealtime.xiff.conference.Room;
import org.igniterealtime.xiff.core.UnescapedJID;
import org.igniterealtime.xiff.core.XMPPConnection;
import org.igniterealtime.xiff.events.LoginEvent;

private var con:XMPPConnection;
private var room:Room;

private function login (username:String, password:String): void {
    con = new XMPPConnection ();
    con.username = username + "@mydomain";
    con.password = password;
    con.server = "localhost";
    con.port = 5222;
    con.connect (0);
}
```

However I am unable to connect to connect to the XMPP server using the ActionScript code above. Just wondering where I may be going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cross-domain policy issue. Try:

1. [Locate your policy log file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ec4.html) first
2. Launch your SWF
3. Check policy file contents

Another way of doing the same thing is opening browser networking log and checking if Flash is trying to load file like `http://localhost/crossdomain.xml`.

There are two general solutions to this problem:

- Serve [correct `crossdomain.xml` from your server](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf) **OR**
- Serve SWF file from the same host as the XMPP data

For debugging purposes [adding SWF file location do local-trusted sandbox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000459.html) should resolve all the issues.